# How to calculate the exponential of a matrix in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90

I have a 4*4 complex matrix. I am looking for an intrinsic function in Fortran 90 to calculate the matrix exponential.

Answer (score 2):

As FORTRAN doesn't have any built in routine for evaluating the Matrix exponentiation. Having said that there are some very useful library available that can do that.

Have a look at the Expokit* software package.

*[Expokit homepage](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/)

Comment: Are you connected to the authors of the library?

Comment: No, but I have used it for my own research work and it is a good library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic fortran function that can do that.